# Getting insufficient Privileges error on custom field only when in inputField or outputField

Tags: visualforce, security, field-level-security, insufficient-privileges

I have a custom field on the Service Contract that I am referencing on a Visualforce Page, which is getting this Insufficient Privileges error:

> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
>   information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

I have narrowed the problem down to this line.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!con.Hosting_Options__c}" rendered="{!IF($ObjectType.ServiceContract.fields.Hosting_Options__c.updateable,True,False)}"/>
```

However, using the following syntax doesn't throw the error:

```
{!con.Hosting_Options__c}
```

As well, the page is correctly displaying several other fields on the same object.

The profile has access to this field and read all/modify all to the object. On the page, both the field accessibility check and the object accessibility check evaluate to true.

What else could be causing this error?

Comment: Are you certain that it isn't due to security settings on the Visualforce page itself? Most times, people will need to update permissions to access a visualforce page after deploying it to a new environment. Providing the entire error message **verbatim** might help.

Comment: Check if the field properties is on the pageLayout set to  'Red Only'

Comment: @Derek F, The message is the same generic insufficient privileges error that I'm sure we've all seen - "Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors." However, the user can see the Page itself when this line is commented out, and can currently see all other fields of the same object/record and can even see this field when it isn't in an input or outputField

Comment: @Viasur, it's not, that was the first ting I checked. The user can even update the field on the standard page layout